# R function/package to Cross-Validate Probability Threshold Value in Making Predictions from Logistic Regression

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, cross-validation

I am currently validating the work of another statistician tasked with developing a logistic model for biomedical data. The data consisted of the following: `metab_x` is a 71 x 186 matrix of 186 clinical chemistry markers measured across 71 patients; `outcome_y` is the patient's disease status, a 71 entry factor vector with case/control levels.

As the title says, I am looking for a function or package that will cross validate the choice of probability threshold value in predicting the class membership of `metab_x` data given a fitted logistic regression model. I have constructed this model using `glm()` in base R. As some others have noted,`predict(object, newdata=metab_x, type="response")` only gives probabilities, not predicted class labels as given here in `outcome_y`. I would like to select the optimum threshold probability value as to minimize prediction error of patient outcomes given `newdata=metab_x`.

I have already tried the `caret` package, but it does not appear to support basic logistic regression, only boosted logistic regression. Otherwise, it's `predict.train` function appears very similar to what I would like to use.

Comment: Are you sure you want to classify class labels? That is missing information!  Search this site for proper scoring rule, the zero-one loss used in classification is not a proper scoring rule.

Comment: If the question is only about how to program your approach in R, it might be off-topic here!